# How to fix "Illegal string offset 'output_key'" in nav_menu.php

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I've got a website on Wordpress and someone in my team updated something and now there is an error on that website:

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'output_key' in /.../wp-includes/nav-menu.php`

I disabled the debug message and now the site is working fine. I guess this is not the best solution. Hours of googling and looking for something here brought me to the fact that I have to tell the script that `'output_key'` is an array element.

```php
$defaults = array( 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 'output' => ARRAY_A, 'output_key' => 'menu_order', 'nopaging' => true );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $args['include'] = $items;


if ( ARRAY_A == $args['output']) {
        $GLOBALS['_menu_item_sort_prop'] = $args['output_key'];
        usort($items, '_sort_nav_menu_items');
        $i = 1;
        foreach( $items as $k => $item ) {
            $items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++; //here is the error
        }
    }
```

I tried to ask `$args` if it is an array in line 1.

```php
$defaults = array( 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item',
        'post_status' => 'publish', 'output' => ARRAY_A, 'output_key' => 'menu_order', 'nopaging' => true );
    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );
    $args['include'] = $items;


if ( ARRAY_A == $args['output'] && is_array($args) ) {
        $GLOBALS['_menu_item_sort_prop'] = $args['output_key'];
        usort($items, '_sort_nav_menu_items');
        $i = 1;
        foreach( $items as $k => $item ) {
            $items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++; //here is the error
        }
    }
```

But line 6 still shows an error on the website. I don't know what to do with that line.

Comment: `$args['output']` is not the same as `$items[$k]->$args['output_key']`.

Comment: should it be the same?
`$defaults = array( 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'post_type' => 'nav_menu_item',
  'post_status' => 'publish', 'output' => ARRAY_A, 'output_key' => 'menu_order', 'nopaging' => true );
 `
the argument 'output' is in there

Comment: well i guess it worked. I disabled the debug messages and it's gone. Thanks @AbraCadaver

Comment: _“I tried to ask $args if it is an array”_ - but the wrong way around … You are trying to access `$args['output']` first, and check if $args is an array second.

Comment: I ran into the same Problem. How did you fix this? Just disable debug messages doesn't seem like a fix for me.

Comment: @Niqql Please share one `var_dump` of `$args`, dumping it in the `foreach` loop. I believe what Abra was actually suggesting is that this is merely a typo, and "_key" should be removed from the key, but I am unsure of  that.

Comment: Sorry, after not finding the error for hours last night I convinced my Client to finally Update the Wordpress Version. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 9):

It seems that you are using an outdated version of wordpress which is no longer compatible with PHP 7.

See [migrating from php 5.6 to php 7 section about variable handling](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.variable-handling.indirect).

[image: variable handling]

Which means that the expression `$items[$k]->$args['output_key']` is interpreted as:

- `$items[$k]->{$args['output_key']}` in PHP 5
- `($items[$k]->$args)['output_key']` in PHP 7

It also seems that this issue is fixed in [recent wordpress code](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/nav-menu.php).

To fix the issue manually, just replace the code:

```
$items[$k]->$args['output_key'] = $i++; // here is the error
```

with:

```
$items[$k]->{$args['output_key']} = $i++; // problem solved :)
```

You should also consider upgrading entire wordpress installation to make sure that the rest of the code is compatible with PHP7.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although I was running on PHP 5.

Comment: Switching my PHP version from 7.1 to 5.6 solved this issue for me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Okay let's go through this easy:

1. Click the right side of the mouse in that purple box. You see option 'inspect'.

   [image]
2. Click the inspect option and you'll see those bunch of codes in the top. Click the code I highlighted.

   [image]
3. Click the three dots beside the highlighted code.

   [image]
4. Click 'delete element' and you're done!

   [image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: All this does is temporarily remove the text from the page in your browser. It doesn't fix the PHP error, and it doesn't prevent your users from seeing it. It won't even permanently remove it from your own browser, if you refresh the page it will be back.